# Where can I find the instance of a page-class in a windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, static-methods

I'm currently programming an app for windows phone 8.1. I've some page classes and one normal C# class in this project.
On the page I'm currently working on are some texboxes, comboboxes and one button.

I want to enable the button, whene the user has given input to all text- and comboboxes. So I set a variable in the C# class **Variables.cs** whene e.g. he entered a number which I can parse to double and selected an item in a combobox. **Variables.cs** looks like this:

```
class Variables
{
    public static int iSelectedIndex = -1;

    private static void SupplyParameterReady()
    {
        if (tbSupply1 && tbSupply2 && unitSupply1 && unitSupply2)
        {
            SupplyParameter.ParameterCompleted(true);
        }
        else
        {
            SupplyParameter.ParameterCompleted(false);
        }
    }

    public static bool tbSupply1
    {
        get
        {
            return tbSupply1;
        }
        set
        {
            tbSupply1 = value;
            if (value)
                SupplyParameterReady();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time a variable is set `true` the method `SupplyParameterReady()` checks if all the other variables are `true` too.

If this is the case I want to call the method `ParameterCompleted(bool)` in my page class, looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class SupplyParameter : Page
{
    ...
    public void ParameterCompleted(bool ready)
    {
        btnSupplyCalculationGo.IsEnabled = ready;
    }
}
```

This brings the issue that `ParameterCompleted(bool)` isn't static. So I need to have an instance of the class `SupplyParameter`.
But don't want to create a new instance of it, because that brings an infinite loop between the 2 classes.

I guess there has to be already an instance, which is created when the page is loaded. But where is this instance? Or how can I call this method without an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move things around, you could have a (non static) `Variables` member inside your `SupplyParameter` Page and pass `this` to the constructor. It would look like this

```
class Variables
{
    public int iSelectedIndex = -1;

    public SupplyParameter _page;

    public Variables(SupplyParameter page)
    {
         _page = page;
    }

    private void SupplyParameterReady()
    {
        if (tbSupply1 && tbSupply2 && unitSupply1 && unitSupply2)
        {
            _page.ParameterCompleted(true);
        }
        else
        {
            _page.ParameterCompleted(false);
        }
    }

    public bool tbSupply1
    {
        get
        {
            return tbSupply1;
        }
        set
        {
            tbSupply1 = value;
            if (value)
                SupplyParameterReady();
        }
    }
}

public sealed partial class SupplyParameter : Page
{
    Variables _vars;

    public SupplyParameter()
    {
        vars = new Variables(this);
    }

    ...

    public void ParameterCompleted(bool ready)
    {
        btnSupplyCalculationGo.IsEnabled = ready;
    }
}
```